# Déjà Dup doesn't open a window when doing the backup

Tags: 18.04, deja-dup

I have updated to 18.04.1 from 16.04.5 a few weeks ago and I noticed that Déjà Dup doesn't open a window when doing the backup like it used to (as far as I can say, the backup is done without problem). I found this convenient as it helped to know when the backup is finished.

Is that normal ? Is that an option ?

Thanks in advance,
Mathieu

Comment: Does any body have an idea ?

Comment: Digging a bit in dejadup configuration with dconf-editor, I noticed that there is a key called "welcomed" that has no schema. Could it be the cause ? Also I noticed that if I launch the backup manually (via the backup interface) then the usual GUI appears.

Comment: Well, removing the `welcomed` key is not enough.

Comment: I reported the problem [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/674766) but it's now closed. @RHertel answer provides a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. After upgrading to 18.04 I couldn't find the window of the déjà-dup backup as it doesn't open automatically any more when the scheduled backup is launched. But I found that there is a notification that can be seen by clicking in the panel on the top in the middle, where the date is displayed, stating that the scheduled backup has been launched. Clicking on that notification will open the usual window which displays the progress of the backup.

Comment: Thanks. I discovered that too (see [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+question/674766)) but forgot to mention it here. I'm not 100% satisfied by this workaround because the window closes at the end of the backup which is not what I would like.